# how to get data from 3 tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Location table
-----------------------------------------------
|location.id|country.id|state.id|city.id|

Country
-----------------------------------------------
|country.id|country|

State
-----------------------------------------------
|state.id|state|

City
-----------------------------------------------
|city.id|city|
```

Now i have location.id, i need to fetch country, city,state names all at once from the location.id.

Need help with Sql query to solve this

Comment: What queries have you already tried?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1984E5m

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php

Comment: this is a simple query - you will need to JOIN the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but you may want to try something like this, and look up [inner joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
select * from locations
inner join Country on `Country`.`country.id` = locations.`country.id`
inner join State on `State`.`state.id` = locations.`state.id`
inner join City on `City`.`city.id` = locations.`city.id`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT location.id, city.city, state.state,country.country
FROM location,city,state,country
WHERE location.country_id = country.id
AND location.city_id = city.id
AND location.state_id = state.id
```